# Center alignment of text with container on the side

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am creating a profile page and need some help with alignment. I need the "username" `text` to be centred vertically and then have a container hosting a circle next to it.

1. What I have:

[image]

2. What I need:

[image]

The difference might be subtle, but as you can see the "username" in #2, is vertical to the entire screen and the circle then proceeds it. However, in case #1, both the "username" and the circle are vertically centred. How can I fix my alignment to get case #2.

My Code:

```html
Container _buildUsername() {
      return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
          top: 1.0,
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(
              "username",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: AppTheme.define().hintColor,
                fontFamily: 'RobotoMedium',
                fontSize: 11.5,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 3.0,
                left: 5.0,
              ),
              child: Container(
                width: 4.2,
                height: 4.2,
                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                  color: AppTheme.define().primaryColor,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope You're Doing Well!
The Easy Way Is To Center The Text Between Two Icons In A Row The First One In Invisible And The Second One Is Your Online Icon (Make Sure To Put The Size Of The First Icon As The Second One)

**Something Like This**

```
 Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Icon(
          Icons.settings_outlined,
          color: Colors.black,// this is should be hidden icon
          size: 24,
        ),
        Text(
          'username',             
          ),
        ),
        Icon(
          Icons.settings_outlined,
          color: Colors.yellow,
          size: 24,
        )
      ],
    )
```